# Accessing an external hard drive via WebDAV

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, external-hard-drive, raspberry-pi, webdav

im new in Linux / Server Administration. I want to access an external hard drive (USB-Stick) through a WebDav client. I'm using a Raspberry Pi in my local network. Is it possible to redirect from [ip]/webdav to that USB stick, that I've mounted already in /media/harddrive?

I'd really appreciate your help. Thank you very much.

~DevOFVictory

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you need to install a webdav server and make that USB stick available to that webdav server.

Although there are many possible, I have installed FuguHub, which is relatively easy to install and administrate.

```
wget FuguHub.com/releases/raspberrypi/install.sh
chmod +x install.sh
sudo ./install.sh
```

The way it installs is suitable for experimentation on a closed network. But there is sufficient documentation to get everything working.

Comment: Okay, thank you once again for your answer. As I already mentioned above I am a Linux beginner. Could you give me more specific instructions? My question is how do I make a certain folder on the USB stick accessible for WebDav so that I am redirected to /dev/harddrive/data via http://myip/webdav. With kind regards
DevOFVictory